# How to using ceil in dart programming language?

Tags: dart, flutter

For example i have value 1.6174 and i want to to check if digit 4 after dot (4) round up or down in flutter.

Example 1.6174 = 1.617 if 1.6176 = 618.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use this code:

```
var num = 1.6176;
(num*1000).ceil()/1000;
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1c11e8e1352417080cd837a28539e827

Comment: the title says `ceil()` but the example is `round()`

Comment: @sony instead of `ceil` you can use `round` method